# Using a project instead of an area in MVC3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, area

I know how to use areas in MVC3 - and I think it works very well, but I really want to make a higher level of seperation in my project.

I have multiple projects in an empty solution, a Domain project (containing my entities, persistence etc.) - a Framework project with tools, helpers etc.) and a UI project which right  now contains the frontend and an area with the /admin for the solution.

Because a want to have a more clean solution for the UI and the Admin, I want to seperate these into two seperate projects.

How can I route the URL?

The url `/` is pointing at the frontend project.
The url `/admin` is pointing af the backend project.

Comment: I'm considering doing the same as you. Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Your /admin is nothing more than another virtual directory mapped to your admin app. It should work just fine like that, as it's how iis and asp.net works.

Comment: But I want to add the admin project to the existing solution, and compile them together. So there will be a ui.dll and a admin.dll - so that both projects can use the domain project and the framework project...

Comment: Also when compiling and debugging I want both projects to run under the same solution.

Comment: No, you are asking for two separate applications to share the same single app space in asp.net. You cannot have two projects compile into one dll in visual studio. You could try to hack it with ILMerge but the results are probably undefined and won't work the way you want it to. They can still point to the same dlls (domain project and framework project), and can be loaded into the same worker process but they wont compile into one dll. whys that an issue?  fyi http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx